# Having trouble with jquery if statement with css property

Tags: jquery, css

```
function toggleLinkSelection(link){
    if($(link).css('border-top-color') == 'red'){
        $(link).css({'border-top-color': 'transparent'});
    } else {
        $("div[id$='OptionsLink']").css({'border-top-color': 'transparent'});
        $(link).css({'border-top-color': 'red'});
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in my if statement?  It never tests true.  In the browser I inspect item and it should test true.  I've tried replacing red with #F00 and #FF0000 and that doesn't help.
The link variable = #testID
Thanks.

Comment: Umm...try `console.log($(link).css('border-top-color'))` and see what you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

colors are returned in rgb

```
$(link).css('border-top-color')==='rgb(255, 0, 0)'
```

ps: always use 3 equals when you know what the output will be, or you could end up with some nasty surprises

**EDIT:** [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3XFss/) by JesseB (see post below)

Comment: Thanks.  I did try the rgb thing.  My mistake was I needed a space after the commas like so....  'rgb(255, 0, 0)'   Thanks.

Comment: In this scenario what's the difference between == and ===?

Comment: @Dale == will still work because of JavaScripts loose typing and truthy/falsy (vs. hard booleans) nature. But the suggestion is to get into the habit of using === when you are expecting a specific value of a specific type so that JavaScript can't misinterpret your intent. For THIS answer? Might not matter. But it's a good habit to have regardless.

Answer (score 1):

@Sinetheta is right but I was working on it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3XFss/), so I thought I'd post my work ;p